# How to use spring2 with rest and hibernate plugins?

Tags: spring, hibernate, rest

this is about the configuration in my struts.xml:

The rest plugin recommends using

```
<constant name="struts.mapper.class" value="rest" />
<constant value="Controller" name="struts.convention.action.suffix" />
<constant value="true" name="struts.convention.action.mapAllMatches" />
<constant value="rest-default" name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" />
<constant value="rest" name="struts.convention.package.locators" />
```

which doesn't use packages anymore. They are all figured out via the convention plugin.  The fullhibernate-plugin tells me to use

```
<package name="default" extends="hibernate-default">
```

though.

How can I integrate this to get REST *and* hibernate running? What's the correct configuration?

(Currently I am getting a NullPointerException because my Session isn't injected.)

Thank you very much for your help!

**Here is some more context:**

I have a bean class called "Task" that has "Dependees"  (all managed via Hibernate)

```
@ManyToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "TASKLIST_TASK",
    joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TASK_ID"),
    inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "TASKLIST_ID"))
private Set<Task> dependees;
```

this is a fairly huge set so I don't want to use FetchType.EAGER (also I can't, because of another relation which would make it cyclical). When I don't use the hibernate plugin, I can't access the dependees via JSP because the Action/Controller has so close the session before the JSP renders and then lazy fetching doesn't work.
Therefore I need the hibernate plugin - to close the session *after* the jsp was rendered.

The problem is that I dont know how to tell the hibernate plugin that it should inject the session object into my class. It's already annotated as it should ( I guess ) but the hibernate plugin just doesn't look at it.

```
public class TaskDAO {

@SessionTarget
Session session;

@TransactionTarget
Transaction transaction;

...
}
```

In case this is a problem: I use annotations over xml wherever I can...

I think I just need the correct configuration for the rest and hibernate plugin to do their work (simultaneously)!

Comment: Let us know what you researched. Btw looks the problem is due to try serializing hibernate lazy stuff

Comment: Hi dgregory, I think the problem is about the hibernateplugin not injecting it's session... I get a stupid null pointer when accessing the session - Added some more context above!

Answer (score 0):

Okay! The part I was missing is the line

```
<constant value="hibernate-default" name="struts.convention.default.parent.package" />
```

which gives every REST controller the hibernate-default package!

After recompiling the fullhibernate-plugin with hibernate-4.1, I can now use it. The lazy initialization is stil not working, but I am one step further :-)